# Playing various video formats in Raspbian on an RPi 3 B

Tags: raspbian, video

Is it possible to play various video formats (i.e. .mov . mp4 .mp2 etc.) in Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B? If it is how is this accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to play various video formats. There are plenty of solutions. One goes like this:

1. Open a terminal
2. `cd` to the directory containing your video file
3. type `omxplayer` and the name of your video file

If this one (or other video players you could use) are not installed. This works like this:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type: `sudo apt-get install` and the name of the player

**Examples:**

```
sudo apt-get install omxplayer
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: ;) lol I forgot. Thanks again as this was a HUGE help for me!

Comment: Can you possibly let me know if you are getting audio output this way, please? I am actually having trouble with that :)

Comment: I am successfully getting audio output from video using the headphone jack (aux) :)

Answer (score 0):

simple solution. convert the videos to a format that plays. you can use free software right in the repository named 'webff' convert the files to avi set the preset to xvid fullscreen. that preset will play on pi's right out of the box.

the problem is, there are no codecs installed for mpeg4 or others. without codecs, none of your players will play the file. for other format support, you would have to buy the codecs. if you attempt to play a video without the proper codec, the video will get stuck on a frame. but it would still play the audio.

Comment: omxplayer plays that format well